# Link to pimcore object from within plugin

Tags: pimcore

I'm developing a plugin that I would like to link to the existing admin interface components - i.e. link from a grid view to an object crud screen.

I know I can do this using deeplinks like in the examples [here](http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Deeplinks+into+the+pimcore+Admin+Interface).
However I want to maintain my open tabs.

Im using Pimcore 2.0 release. This I would have thought would be a standard feature in the admin section?
Anyone?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle grid item click and call `pimcore.helpers.openObject(id, type);`

For reference you can check [onTreeNodeClick](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/pimcore/static/js/pimcore/object/tree.js#L145)  handler in pimcore.